# Redirect to the Home/main Page after successful log in Angularjs + .Razor view pages?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have ASP.Net MVC5 application with MVC controllers and angular js controllers as front end. I have a login page which after you have succesfully Login wil direct you to the main/Home page (.cshtml). My problem is how do you redirect to the Razor page using Angular js controller?

```
 //angularjs Code
  $scope.Login = function () {
    $scope.Submitted = true;
    if ($scope.IsFormValid) {
        LoginService.GetUser($scope.UserVM).then(function (d) {
            if (d.data.UserName != null) {
                $scope.IsLogedIn = true;
                $scope.Message = "Successfully login done. Welcome " + d.data.UserName;

            }
            else {
                alert('Invalid Credential!');
            }

        });
    }
};

   // _Layout.cshtml (Main Page i want to redirect to after successful Login)
```

Comment: window.location = 'pageThatYouWantToLoad' -> this solution if you want to redirect to another site (and reload) if you want just to render another template you can use ngRoute or ui.roouter and use its methods to redirect and render another view

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is rendering different partials depending on whether users are logged in or not. So one possible solution is leveraging `@RenderPage`

```
@if(!isLoggedIn)
{
    @RenderPage("~/views/login.cshtml");
}
else
{
    <div ng-controller="mainController">
         ....
    </div>
}
```

This way when users logged in you only need to refresh current page and your razor engine would generate a new partial rather than `login.cshtml`.

Comment: I tried the code but im encounting the following Compilation error :

Line 79: <br />
Line 80: 
Line 81: @if (!isIsLoggedIn)
Line 82: {
Line 83:     @RenderPage("~/details.html");    Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'isIsLoggedIn' does not exist in the current context